# Why use typedef before dllimport in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, typedef, dllimport

A company recently sent me an SDK with very little documentation. To complicate matters, I am also a novice at visual c++. The SDK is a number of DLLs along with some header files.

One header file has a number of lines like this:

`typedef __declspec(dllimport) int (*functionName01)();`

and

`typedef __declspec(dllimport) bool (*functionName02)(void *data);`

I understand that we need to "import" or get the address of the function in memory, once loaded, and define what the inputs/outputs are. However, its not clear to me why this line starts with "typedef".

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A `typedef` is an *alias name* for the type, which is usually a lot easier to read than spelling out the entire type.

Comment: As Eljay said above, these are aliases to function pointer types. There will be a similar variable declaration ahead that uses this type, and then this variable will be eventually initialized with the address of the corresponding dynamically loaded function from a dll typically.